# How do I send key stroke Enter in Watir

Tags: watir, keystroke

I need to automate the action of hitting 'Enter' key on keyboard after entering a text in a text field. 
I tried `@browser.send_keys :enter`
but that does not do the action. also have tried `@browser.text_field(:name => 'q').send_keys :enter` or `@browser.text_field(:name => 'q').focus` and then send_keys. But has not helped.

```
@browser.send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

does not help this too, this actually types ("{ENTER}")

Please let me know other ways of doing?

Answer (score 11):

`browser.send_keys :enter` should do the job. Please provide link to the page, link to a similar page, or relevant HTML.

Comment: <input type="text" size="30" class="searchText" dojoattachpoint="_searchTextAP" id="xwt_widget_uishell_Header17_2_search_searchTextAP" dojoattachevent="onfocus:_onFocus_searchTextAP,onblur:_onBlur_searchTextAP, onkeyup:_onKeyUp_searchTextAP">

Comment: Can someone plz help me out, its urgent..I see these working at  search text field of google.com. But not at my application :( any thoughts?

Comment: @user1771980, did you try asking the developers to see what event they are listening for?

Answer (score 7):

try browse.send_keys :return
found it here http://watirmelon.com/about/

Comment: Here is a [Full List of Special Keys](http://watirmelon.com/2011/07/19/sending-special-keys-to-watir-webdriver/)

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="30" class="searchText" dojoattachpoint="_searchTextAP" id="xwt_widget_uishell_Header17_2_search_searchTextAP" dojoattachevent="onfocus:_onFocus_searchTextAP,onblur:_onBlur_searchTextAP, onkeyup:_onKeyUp_searchTextAP">
```

It looks like the element is listening for these events (via dojo): `onfocus`, `onblur`, `onKeyUp`

To trigger these events, you'll need to use something like this:

```
browser.text_field(:id => /.*searchTextAP$/).focus
browser.element(:id => 'someOtherElement').focus
browser.text_field(:id => /.*searchTextAP$/).fire_event "onkeyup"
```

If you want to submit the form, you probably need to click the submit button (since you mentioned hitting `:enter`):

```
browser.button(:type => 'submit').click
```

If you really wanted to just send the `:enter` key, one of the other answers should work.